# Deleting pointer after async call

Tags: c++, azure, visual-c++, concurrency, azure-storage

I m trying to upload a file to azure storage and I would like to leverage the async feature. however I m having hard time to know if the cleanup is done correctly.

I would like to delete file data, and release all streams but obviously it should be done after the upload is complete.

Any comments on how I can improve that to make it more robust?

```
Concurrency::task<void> BlobService::UploadAsync(
    cloud_blob_container container, const wchar_t* blobName,
    uint8_t * data, size_t dataLength,
    const wchar_t* contentType, const wchar_t* cacheControl) {

    rawptr_buffer<uint8_t>* buffer = new rawptr_buffer<uint8_t>(data, dataLength);
    istream inputStream = buffer->create_istream();

    cloud_block_blob blob = container.get_block_blob_reference(utility::string_t(blobName));
    blob.properties().set_content_type(utility::string_t(contentType));
    blob.properties().set_cache_control(utility::string_t(cacheControl));

    azure::storage::blob_request_options options;
    options.set_maximum_execution_time(std::chrono::seconds(10800));
    options.set_server_timeout(std::chrono::seconds(10800));

    azure::storage::access_condition access;
    azure::storage::operation_context context;

    return blob.upload_from_stream_async(inputStream, access, options, context).then([buffer, inputStream, data] {
        buffer->close().wait();
        inputStream.close().wait();

        delete[] data;
        delete buffer;
    });

}
```

Comment: Do you have any indication that your presented solution is not correct? I'm a bit weary when I see manual delete calls, so it might not clean up correctly when exceptions are thrown, but otherwise the structure seems correct to me

Comment: No I m having a synchronous version of it that runs in production, and the server is not very stable but I don't know if it's related... so I m going over all the potentials issues and try to make sure the cleanup is done.

the delete[] data doesn't worry my too much, but the close and delete of stream more

Comment: Minor off-topic comment:  `hours{3}` would be more readable than `seconds{10800}` and have identical functionality.